# R Case statement using both and or in the same statement - between Dates, some with missing values over multiple columns

Tags: r

I'm trying to see whether or not a program participant was active on the beginning of each month.

I have program start and end dates, but some of these participants are still enrolled in the program, so the end date is null.

My table has the first two columns, but I would like the remaining columns to be populated with a case statement like this:

```
case when Date > Admission and (Date < Discharge or Discharge is null) then 'Active' else 'Inactive'
```

with date being the first day of the month column 
(I already have columns pre-populated with this date so the equation can be done row by row)

```
Admission Discharge Jan-19   Feb-19   Mar-19
12/3/18   4/3/19    Active   Active   Active
01/7/19   NA        Inactive Active   Active
02/25/19  03/02/19  Inactive Inactive Active
```

I've tried ifelse and if statements, but can't figure out how to do both the multiple conditions. If all else fails, I will use the sqldf package, but am hoping there is a way to do this in R with a loop as more recent months will be added as time goes on.

I tried running this snippet of code, but it does not work with missing discharge dates

```
Dates$`Sep-2018` <- ifelse(Dates$`Sep-2018` > Dates$Admission_Date & Dates$`Sep-2018` < Dates$Discharge_Date, "Active",
       ifelse(Dates$`Sep-2018` > Dates$Admission_Date & is.na(Dates$Discharge_Date), "Active", "Inactive"))
```

Is there a way to apply the case statement across multiple columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dynamic variable creation of dplyr:

```
library(dplyr) # version 0.6 and above
library(lubridate)

df <- df %>% 
  select(Admission, Discharge) %>% 
  mutate_all(mdy) # convert the columns to date format

# Start dates of the months and respective month names
my_months <- ymd("2019-01-01", "2019-02-01", "2019-03-01", "2019-04-01")
month_names <- month(my_months, label=T) %>% as.character()


# Looping through the months and dynamic creation of month columns
for (i in seq(length(my_months))){
  df <- df %>%  
    mutate(!!month_names[i] := ifelse(my_months[i] > Admission &
                                        (my_months[i] < Discharge | is.na(Discharge)), 
                                        "Active", "NotActive"))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit clunky, but if you want to do a for loop you could do something like this:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  startDate<-df[i,1] #Puts the start date in assuming the admission column is column 1
  endDate<-df[i,2] #Puts the end date in assuming the discharge column is column 2
  for(z in 3:ncol(df)){ #Starts at the date column
    colValue<-colnames(df[z]) #Gives the value of the column name
    if(startDate>colValue){ #If the participant has not been enrolled yet
      df[i,z]<-"Inactive"
    }
    if(startDate<colValue){ #If the startdate is before the value of the column
      if(colValue<endDate | is.null(endDate)){
        df[i,z]<-"Active"
      }else{
        df[i,z]<="Inactive"
      }
    }
    }
  }
```

Hopefully I understood your question correctly and this works. If it does not then the dates would likely need to be converted to POSIXct datetimes in R.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, this can be solved using a combined *cross join* and *non-equi join* and subsequent reshaping from long to wide format.

```
library(data.table)
months <- seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), Sys.Date(), by = "month")
cbind(
  dates,
  setDT(dates)[, lapply(.SD, as.Date, format = "%m/%d/%y")][
    is.na(Discharge), Discharge := Sys.Date()][
      , rn := .I][
        .(months), on = .(Admission <= V1, Discharge >= V1)
        , allow.cartesian = TRUE, .(rn, V1, active = "Active")][
          , V1 := factor(V1, labels = format(months, "%b-%y"))][
          , dcast(.SD, rn ~ V1, value.var = "active", fill = "Inactive")][
            , rn := NULL]
)
```

> ```
>    Admission Discharge   Jan-19   Feb-19 Mrz-19   Apr-19   Mai-19   Jun-19
> 1:   12/3/18    4/3/19   Active   Active Active   Active Inactive Inactive
> 2:   01/7/19      <NA> Inactive   Active Active   Active   Active   Active
> 3:  02/25/19  03/02/19 Inactive Inactive Active Inactive Inactive Inactive
> ```

#### Explanation

1. `months` contains a vector of reference dates. Here, the first day of each month is used.
2. The `Admission` and `Discharge` dates are coerced from character to `Date` class to allow for date calculation.
3. Any missing `Discharge` dates are filled up by the current date.
4. A row number is added to keep the original row order in the subsequent reshape.
5. Then this is right-joined with `months`. It is a *non-equi cross join* which returns only cases where the first day of the month `V1` is between the admission and discharge dates. `V1` is the default column name created when turning the `months` vector into a list by `.(months)`.  `allow.cartesian = TRUE` indicates the cross join. In the join, a new column `active` is created with a default value of `"Active"`.
6. `V1` is turned into a factor with appropriately named months, e.g., `"Jan-19"`, `"Feb-19"`, etc. This ensures that dates will appear in the proper order (instead of being sorted lexicographically) in the subsequent reshape.
7. `dcast()` reshapes the data from long to wide format while missing entries are filled up with `"Inactive"`.
8. The row numbers are removed.
9. Finally, the result is combined with the original `dates` dataset using `cbind()`.

#### Shorter version

Above code tries to reproduce OP's expected result as close as possible. The same information (but in a different appearance) can be retrieved using a more concise code:

```
setDT(dates)[, lapply(.SD, as.Date, format = "%m/%d/%y")][
  is.na(Discharge), Discharge := Sys.Date()][
    , rn := .I][
      .(months), on = .(Admission <= V1, Discharge >= V1), allow.cartesian = TRUE
      , .(rn, Admission = x.Admission, Disscharge = x.Discharge, V1)][
        , dcast(.SD, rn + ... ~ V1, length)]
```

which returns

> ```
>    rn  Admission Disscharge 2019-01-01 2019-02-01 2019-03-01 2019-04-01 2019-05-01 2019-06-01
> 1:  1 2018-12-03 2019-04-03          1          1          1          1          0          0
> 2:  2 2019-01-07 2019-06-07          0          1          1          1          1          1
> 3:  3 2019-02-25 2019-03-02          0          0          1          0          0          0
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
dates <- fread("Admission Discharge Jan-19   Feb-19   Mar-19
12/3/18   4/3/19    Active   Active   Active
01/7/19   NA        Inactive Active   Active
02/25/19  03/02/19  Inactive Inactive Active"
            , select = 1:2)

dates
```

> ```
>    Admission Discharge
> 1:   12/3/18    4/3/19
> 2:   01/7/19      <NA>
> 3:  02/25/19  03/02/19
> ```